# the list inside a list of lisp tutorial

Tags: lisp, elisp

I am reading  [Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eintr.html)

```
Here is another list, this time with a list inside of it:

     '(this list has (a list inside of it))
```

I am confused with the nested list, why it has not a prefix quoting  as

```
 '(this list has  '(a list inside of it))
```

if not has a prefix `, why it not parse the a as a function?

Comment: It's very important to understand that `'`, which means `(quote ...)`, is not a shorthand for making lists. It's a form which causes lisp to return, unevaluated, the object that was created by the lisp reader.   I recommend that at some point in your learning process you doing some reading about the distinct `read` and `eval` phases of lisp execution. Once you understand the distinction, `quote` will make much more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'s-expression` is an abbreviation for `(quote s-expression)`: anything inside the *s-expression* is considered a datum and it is not evaluated.

So,

```
'(this list has (a list inside of it))
```

is an abbreviation of:

```
(quote (this list has (a list inside of it)))
```

that contains the following list:

```
(this list has (a list inside of it))
```

which is the value of the entire `quote` form since it is not evaluated.

It is easy to verify this by writing:

```
'(this list has '(a list inside of it))
```

This, if evaluated, will produce as value the following list:

```
(this list has (quote (a list inside of it)))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the slight difficulties in Lisp: a list is data and can also be a program. If you want a list to be data in a Lisp program, you need to quote it.

**Lists as such: one can read them with READ**

```
(this list has (a list inside of it))
(this list has no list inside of it)
(+ 1 2)
(1 2 +)
(1 + 2)
(quote (this list has (a list inside of it)))
(quote (this list has (quote (a quote list inside of it))))
(quote quote)
```

**Valid Lisp forms: one can evaluate them with EVAL**

```
(+ 1 2)
Evaluates to -> 3

(quote (+ 1 2))
Evaluates to -> (+ 1 2)

(quote (this list has (a list inside of it)))
Evaluates to -> (this list has (a list inside of it))

(quote quote)
Evaluates to -> quote
```

This is also a valid Lisp form:

```
(quote (this list has (quote (a quoted list inside of it))))
```

It evaluates to:

```
(this list has (quote (a quoted list inside of it)))
```